Why are the expressions divided by 2 random elements $\gamma$ & $\delta$ in Groth16?
In Groth16 Page 14
The prover does
$C = \frac {\sum_{i = l+1}^m a_i ( \beta u_i(x) + \alpha v_i(x) + w_i(x)) + h(x)t(x)}{\delta} + As + r\beta − rs\delta$
And the verifier
$A \cdot B = \alpha \cdot \beta + \frac {\sum_{i=0}^{l} a_i (\beta u_i(x) + \alpha v_i(x) + w_i(x)) }{\gamma} \cdot \gamma + C \cdot \delta$
On Page 15, an explanation is given

The role of $\gamma$ and $\delta$ is to make the two latter products of the verification equation independent from the first product, by dividing the left factors with $\gamma$ and $\delta$ respectively. This prevents mixing and matching of elements intended for different products in the verification equation.

I am unable to understand this - what does it mean "two latter products of the verification equation independent from the first product"
What is the mixing & matching being talked about & what kind of attack is prevented by doing this?


"Two latter products of the verification equation independent from the first product" - Recall that from the construction, $A, B, C$ are linear combinations of $$\sigma = \left ( \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, 
\{x^i\}^{n−1}_{i=0} ,
\left\{ \frac{\beta u_i(x)+ \alpha v_i(x)+ w_i(x)}{\gamma} \right\}^{\ell}_{
i=0} ,
\left\{ \frac{\beta u_i(x)+ \alpha v_i(x)+w_i(x)}{\delta} \right\}^{m}_{i=\ell+ 1},
\left\{ \frac{x^i t(x)}{\delta} \right\}^{n−2}_{i=0} \right )$$
As mentioned on page 15, we can view $A, B$ and $C$ as formal polynomials
in indeterminates $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, x$. Now the product $C \cdot \delta$ does not contain a term $\alpha \beta$, making it independent from the first product (which is $\alpha \beta$) in the verification equation. Similarly, because of $\gamma$, the second product (which is just a linear polynomial in $\alpha$ and $\beta$) in the verification equation is also independent of $\alpha \beta$.
"This prevents the mixing and matching of elements" - By meticulously using $\gamma$ and $\delta$, the right-hand side of the verification equation does not contain unnecessary factors of $\alpha^2, \beta^2, \frac{1}{\delta^2}, \frac{1}{\gamma^2},$ etc. (see proof of Theorem 1). Eventually, this will help one to show that $A$ and $B$ given by the (malicious) affine prover will be of the form $A = \alpha + A(x) + A_{\delta} \delta $ and $B = \alpha + B(x) + B_{\delta} \delta $ which is very similar to the $A$ and $B$ generated in the $\mathsf{Prove}(R, \sigma, a_1, \dots , a_m)$. And later continues to extract the witness $a_{\ell+1}, \dots, a_{m}$. Since, these calculations does not take into consideration the behaviour of the adversary/prover, the scheme is secure against unbounded adversaries also as stated in Theorem 1 (refer to the definition of statistical knowledge soundness against affine prover strategies).


It may take me a little while to understand your answer, so please bear with me. If the bounty expires, I will add a new bounty to give you if I accept the answer
